# yii RegisterScript, id and type

Tags: jquery, yii, jsrender

I am trying to use [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) on a yii application. 
I need to register a script like this:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>
        {{:#index+1}}: <b>{{:name}}</b> ({{:releaseYear}})
    </div>
</script>
```

usually I use CClientScript::registerScript(); but it does not allow to specify an ID or type.
can anyone suggest a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CClientScript::registerScript()` function registers only javascripts, which will of-course have type `text/javascript`...the scripts you are registering are not javascripts to be understood by browsers, infact they are given custom names as type by the library builders, (in your case jsremder)..to make browser avoid them, so that their javascript can parse it..
Like in underscore.js we have `type="text/template"`..

You need to include it manually..

Answer (score 1):

Just include your template in a view file, ClientScript isn't suitable for it.